# Connect to mysql through Xcode - will appstore allow it?

Tags: mysql, database, xcode

I'm very new to obj-c, and I'm doing this app where you click an annotation, which takes you to the country. I want to connect to MySql with an external php script:

```
<?php
include("connect.php");

$land = $_GET['land'];

$res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM lande WHERE name = '$land'");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($res);

$flag = $row['flag'];

echo $flag;
echo $land;

?>
```

and here is my button in Xcode:

```
-(void)button:(id)sender {

 if (mapView.selectedAnnotations.count == 0)
 {
    //no annotation is currently selected
    return;
 }


 id<MKAnnotation> selectedAnn = [mapView.selectedAnnotations objectAtIndex:0];
 country_title = selectedAnn.title;


 UIViewController* Countries = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Countries" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

 NSString *strUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://localhost:8888/app/country.php?land=%@",country_title];

 NSData *dataURL = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strUrl]];

 NSString *strResult = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataURL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

 NSLog(@"%@",strResult);


 [self.view addSubview:Countries.view];

}
```

How do I print out my results?
and is this at all legal? Will appstore allow this?
Is there another way to do it? I know SQLite but it seems very difficult ... :(

Comment: Regardless of whether Apple will allow it, iOS won't run PHP code. Your best bet is to load up a server somewhere else that handles all the PHP, and then returns the values (as XML or JSON, likely). There are ways to run PHP code on iOS, but I'm a champion of native code so I can't in good conscience recommend any of them.

Answer (score 1):

There is no rules against using outside database resources in your application. I use this method all the time to include extra data that is constantly changing that can't be stored locally. However, you do not have a PHP server on your device, so to do this fully you'll need to connect to a remote server.

If you are dead set on doing it all locally might want to read up a bit on SQLite, if you can do MySQL you'll be fine working with SQLite.